# Square Node SDK API calls return "Unauthorized" error

Tags: node.js, authorization, access-token, square

I'm currently trying to use three of the square apis through their node.js square-connect package. However, I cannot seem to access any of them due to an authorization error. The code I use to authorize (Using the node sdk) can be seen below.
Note: I have replaced "my token" and "my location" with the correct values.

```
var oauth2 = square.ApiClient.instance.authentications['oauth2'];
oauth2.accessToken = 'My token'; //Production accessToken
var customerApi = new square.CustomersApi();
var catalogApi = new square.CatalogApi();
var ordersApi = new square.OrdersApi();
var locationId = "My location"; //production location
```

I then use the Square SDK to make the API calls as such (this is only one example)

```
async function searchCustomers(data) {
    var body = {
        query: {
            filter: {
                reference_id: {
                    exact: data.member.toString() //We are filtering the customers by an exact match with the reference id (member id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return await customerApi.searchCustomers(body).then(function (data) {
        // Note: We only return the first customer
        if (data.customers.length <= 0) {
            console.log("No customers found to have a membership id of: " + data.member);
            return null;
        }
        console.log('search Customers API called successfully. Returned data: ' + data);
        return data.customers[0]; // This should be a customer object
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log("Could not search customers.", e)
        return null;
    })
```

The error message:

```
Could not search customers. { Error: Unauthorized
0|maaNode  |     at Request.callback (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:706:15)
0|maaNode  |     at parser (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:916:18)
0|maaNode  |     at IncomingMessage.res.on (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:19:7)
0|maaNode  |     at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
0|maaNode  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
0|maaNode  |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
0|maaNode  |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
0|maaNode  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
0|maaNode  |   status: 401,
0|maaNode  |   response: 
0|maaNode  |    Response {
0|maaNode  |      domain: null,
0|maaNode  |      _events: {},
0|maaNode  |      _eventsCount: 0,
0|maaNode  |      _maxListeners: undefined,
0|maaNode  |      res: 
0|maaNode  |       IncomingMessage {
0|maaNode  |         _readableState: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         readable: false,
0|maaNode  |         domain: null,
0|maaNode  |         _events: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         _eventsCount: 4,
0|maaNode  |         _maxListeners: undefined,
0|maaNode  |         socket: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         connection: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         httpVersionMajor: 1,
0|maaNode  |         httpVersionMinor: 1,
0|maaNode  |         httpVersion: '1.1',
0|maaNode  |         complete: true,
0|maaNode  |         headers: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         rawHeaders: [Array],
0|maaNode  |         trailers: {},
0|maaNode  |         rawTrailers: [],
0|maaNode  |         upgrade: false,
0|maaNode  |         url: '',
0|maaNode  |         method: null,
0|maaNode  |         statusCode: 401,
0|maaNode  |         statusMessage: 'Unauthorized',
0|maaNode  |         client: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         _consuming: true,
0|maaNode  |         _dumped: false,
0|maaNode  |         req: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         text: '{"errors": [{"code": "UNAUTHORIZED","detail": "The `Authorization` http header of your request was malformed. The header value is expected to be of the format \\"Bearer TOKEN\\" (without quotation marks), where TOKEN is to be replaced with your access token (e.g. \\"Bearer ABC123def456GHI789jkl0\\"). For more information, see https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#requestandresponseheaders. If you are seeing this error message while using one of our officially supported SDKs, please report this to developers@squareup.com.","category": "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR"}]}\n',
0|maaNode  |         read: [Function] },
0|maaNode  |      request: 
0|maaNode  |       Request {
0|maaNode  |         domain: null,
0|maaNode  |         _events: {},
0|maaNode  |         _eventsCount: 0,
0|maaNode  |         _maxListeners: undefined,
0|maaNode  |         _agent: false,
0|maaNode  |         _formData: null,
0|maaNode  |         method: 'POST',
0|maaNode  |         url: 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/customers/search',
0|maaNode  |         _header: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         header: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         writable: true,
0|maaNode  |         _redirects: 0,
0|maaNode  |         _maxRedirects: 5,
0|maaNode  |         cookies: '',
0|maaNode  |         qs: {},
0|maaNode  |         _query: [],
0|maaNode  |         qsRaw: [],
0|maaNode  |         _redirectList: [],
0|maaNode  |         _streamRequest: false,
0|maaNode  |         _timeout: 60000,
0|maaNode  |         _responseTimeout: 0,
0|maaNode  |         _data: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         req: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         protocol: 'https:',
0|maaNode  |         host: 'connect.squareup.com',
0|maaNode  |         _endCalled: true,
0|maaNode  |         _callback: [Function],
0|maaNode  |         res: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         response: [Circular],
0|maaNode  |         called: true },
0|maaNode  |      req: 
0|maaNode  |       ClientRequest {
0|maaNode  |         domain: null,
0|maaNode  |         _events: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         _eventsCount: 3,
0|maaNode  |         _maxListeners: undefined,
0|maaNode  |         output: [],
0|maaNode  |         outputEncodings: [],
0|maaNode  |         outputCallbacks: [],
0|maaNode  |         outputSize: 0,
0|maaNode  |         writable: true,
0|maaNode  |         _last: true,
0|maaNode  |         upgrading: false,
0|maaNode  |         chunkedEncoding: false,
0|maaNode  |         shouldKeepAlive: false,
0|maaNode  |         useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
0|maaNode  |         sendDate: false,
0|maaNode  |         _removedConnection: false,
0|maaNode  |         _removedContLen: false,
0|maaNode  |         _removedTE: false,
0|maaNode  |         _contentLength: 52,
0|maaNode  |         _hasBody: true,
0|maaNode  |         _trailer: '',
0|maaNode  |         finished: true,
0|maaNode  |         _headerSent: true,
0|maaNode  |         socket: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         connection: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         _header: 'POST /v2/customers/search HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: connect.squareup.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Square-Connect-Javascript/4.20200722.1\r\nAuthorization: Bearer EAAAEE117sYcLvlA_aBSNFjFk1q6OQivIvdP1LJoYmA-FxEsbd-pRC7NHz6PpFcz\r\nSquare-Version: 2020-07-22\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 52\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
0|maaNode  |         _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
0|maaNode  |         agent: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         socketPath: undefined,
0|maaNode  |         timeout: undefined,
0|maaNode  |         method: 'POST',
0|maaNode  |         path: '/v2/customers/search',
0|maaNode  |         _ended: true,
0|maaNode  |         res: [Object],
0|maaNode  |         aborted: undefined,
0|maaNode  |         timeoutCb: null,
0|maaNode  |         upgradeOrConnect: false,
0|maaNode  |         parser: null,
0|maaNode  |         maxHeadersCount: null,
0|maaNode  |         [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
0|maaNode  |      text: '{"errors": [{"code": "UNAUTHORIZED","detail": "The `Authorization` http header of your request was malformed. The header value is expected to be of the format \\"Bearer TOKEN\\" (without quotation marks), where TOKEN is to be replaced with your access token (e.g. \\"Bearer ABC123def456GHI789jkl0\\"). For more information, see https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#requestandresponseheaders. If you are seeing this error message while using one of our officially supported SDKs, please report this to developers@squareup.com.","category": "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR"}]}\n',
0|maaNode  |      body: { errors: [Array] },
0|maaNode  |      files: undefined,
0|maaNode  |      buffered: true,
0|maaNode  |      headers: 
0|maaNode  |       { date: 'Mon, 24 Aug 2020 14:55:16 GMT',
0|maaNode  |         'frame-options': 'DENY',
0|maaNode  |         'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
0|maaNode  |         'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
0|maaNode  |         'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
0|maaNode  |         'content-type': 'application/json',
0|maaNode  |         'content-length': '574',
0|maaNode  |         'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000; includeSubDomains; preload',
0|maaNode  |         connection: 'close' },
0|maaNode  |      header: 
0|maaNode  |       { date: 'Mon, 24 Aug 2020 14:55:16 GMT',
0|maaNode  |         'frame-options': 'DENY',
0|maaNode  |         'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
0|maaNode  |         'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
0|maaNode  |         'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
0|maaNode  |         'content-type': 'application/json',
0|maaNode  |         'content-length': '574',
0|maaNode  |         'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000; includeSubDomains; preload',
0|maaNode  |         connection: 'close' },
0|maaNode  |      statusCode: 401,
0|maaNode  |      status: 401,
0|maaNode  |      statusType: 4,
0|maaNode  |      info: false,
0|maaNode  |      ok: false,
0|maaNode  |      redirect: false,
0|maaNode  |      clientError: true,
0|maaNode  |      serverError: false,
0|maaNode  |      error: 
0|maaNode  |       { Error: cannot POST /v2/customers/search (401)
0|maaNode  |     at Response.toError (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/response.js:94:15)
0|maaNode  |     at ResponseBase._setStatusProperties (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/response-base.js:123:16)
0|maaNode  |     at new Response (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/response.js:41:8)
0|maaNode  |     at Request._emitResponse (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:752:20)
0|maaNode  |     at parser (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:916:38)
0|maaNode  |     at IncomingMessage.res.on (/home/ubuntu/maaWebsite/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:19:7)
0|maaNode  |     at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
0|maaNode  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
0|maaNode  |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
0|maaNode  |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
0|maaNode  |         status: 401,
0|maaNode  |         text: '{"errors": [{"code": "UNAUTHORIZED","detail": "The `Authorization` http header of your request was malformed. The header value is expected to be of the format \\"Bearer TOKEN\\" (without quotation marks), where TOKEN is to be replaced with your access token (e.g. \\"Bearer ABC123def456GHI789jkl0\\"). For more information, see https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#requestandresponseheaders. If you are seeing this error message while using one of our officially supported SDKs, please report this to developers@squareup.com.","category": "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR"}]}\n',
0|maaNode  |         method: 'POST',
0|maaNode  |         path: '/v2/customers/search' },
0|maaNode  |      created: false,
0|maaNode  |      accepted: false,
0|maaNode  |      noContent: false,
0|maaNode  |      badRequest: false,
0|maaNode  |      unauthorized: true,
0|maaNode  |      notAcceptable: false,
0|maaNode  |      forbidden: false,
0|maaNode  |      notFound: false,
0|maaNode  |      unprocessableEntity: false,
0|maaNode  |      type: 'application/json',
0|maaNode  |      links: {},
0|maaNode  |      setEncoding: [Function: bound ],
0|maaNode  |      redirects: [] } }
```

Is there something I can fix on my side, or is this an issue with the node SDK?

Comment: Unauthorized means the access token is invalid. Can you confirm that you're using production? If you're using sandbox credentials, you need to change the `basePath` on the ApiClient object.

Comment: I am using the production access token.

Comment: @sjosey I'm currently getting the access token from the developer portal. Is there another access token I should be using?

Comment: No, that sounds correct to me. Could you reach out to developer support so we can ask for more information and take a look at the logs? https://squareup.com/help/contact?panel=BF53A9C8EF68